# ListView always show scrollbar inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, listview

I know this has been asked infinity times already but I'v tried all the solutions and had no results.

I want the vertical scrollbars to always show on the screen.

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingRight="16dp"
              android:paddingLeft="16dp"
              android:background="#ffacb8ba"
              android:fadeScrollbars="false"
              android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
              android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my code, I also set

```
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

I think the issue might be related to the fact that the listview is inside a swiperefreshlayout, I don't know.

HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after looking into the documention: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(boolean)

Turns out setting the scrollbar always visible is separate from always showing fastscroll :)